# php explode all characters

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I'm looking for the equivalent of what in js would be `'this is a string'.split('')` for PHP.

If I try `$array = explode('', 'testing');` I get an error `Warning: explode() [function.explode]: Empty delimiter in`

Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

As indicated by your error, `explode` requires a delimiter to split the string. Use [`str_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) instead:

```
$arr = str_split('testing');
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => t
    [1] => e
    [2] => s
    [3] => t
    [4] => i
    [5] => n
    [6] => g
)
```

Comment: what about accents?

Answer (score 8):

Use the [`str_split`](http://php.net/str_split) function.

```
$array = str_split( 'testing');
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$string = "TEST";

echo $string[0];  // This will display T
```

There is no need to explode it

Comment: How would you create array from the string, each character as a separate element in the array?

Comment: PHP looks at it as an array automatically if you treat it as one, and gives each character a key based on it's position.

Comment: Oh, really? See this: http://codepad.org/SRsULXQE ("_Warning: array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array_"). -1

Comment: He meant to say: "PHP will index a string like an array". But it is not an array and cannot be used on functions that require array inputs. However, you can loop over a string and extract an individual character with the same notation as an array with a `for` loop over the `strlen` of the string.

Answer (score 0):

TO SPLIT string into ARRAY its best to use

```
$arr= str_split($string);
```